# Downloading files from S3 much faster on local host than from EC2 instance?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm running a fairly simple Python script which uses multiprocessing and requests to download files from S3. When I run this script locally, it's very fast (5k images in 2.5 minutes). When I run the same exact script on an EC2 instance (g2.2xlarge, since I need to use a GPU instance), it's extremely slow (on the order of 10X slower), even though I am using optimized EBS and gave it 3600 IOPs. At this point I have no idea what I should be checking. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

The script was modified from here, by replacing urllib2 with requests:

https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/finetune_flickr_style/assemble_data.py

Comment: Perhaps post the script here?  Disk I/O can be a huge factor.  Have you tried downloading the files to `os.devnull` to eliminate local disk I/O as a factor? What is the difference in latency between your local environment to your S3 target versus your EC2 instance?  Can you ping it from both?

Comment: What region is your S3 bucket in, and what region is your EC2 instance in?

Comment: I figured it out. The issue is most likely that I was being throttled by S3. When I switched from requests to boto3, it's now even faster than my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely related to CDN throttling my http requests made from the EC2 instance. When I switched over to using boto, the speed became comparable to what I was doing locally.

Hope this helps someone not waste time like I did! Just use boto, when in doubt.

Comment: S3 doesn't throttle requests based on what you are using to access it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Do you have an alternative explanation?

Comment: Not really, but the suggestion that S3 somehow prefers to be accessed by one library rather than another is unjustifiable speculation.  There's only one way in and out of S3, and that's via the REST API.  When S3 throttles requests, which is rare, it returns the HTTP error `503 Slow Down`.  It does not just move more slowly.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot After doing some more digging, the most likely explanation we came up with is that the throttling was actually coming from our CDN, not S3.